# crashed when running coreml batch prediction from background to foreground

Tags: coreml

this is my code:

```
id<MLBatchProvider> outBatch = [_model predictionsFromBatch:inBatch options:options error:error];
```

When the app is in the foreground， I submitted the batch  predictions, Then I put the app in to background, and next I put the app to the foreground, the app is crashed.

the crash is :

> Last Exception Backtrace:
>
> 0  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001d427bea0
>   ___exceptionPreprocess +  228
>
> 1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x00000001d344da40
>   objc_exception_throw + 56
>
> 2  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001d41f3470 _CFArgv + 0
>
> 3  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001d4185f4c -[__NSArrayM
>   setObject:atIndexedSubscript:] +  704
>
> 4  CoreML                         0x00000001e31273d4
>   ___53-[MLNeuralNetworkEngine evaluateBatch:options:error:]_block_invoke.649 +  928
>
> 5  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001d3cb56c8
>   __dispatch_call_block_and_release +  24
>
> 6  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001d3cb6484
>   __dispatch_client_callout +  16
>
> 7  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001d3c5dbe0
>   __dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp +  592
>
> 8  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001d3c5e75c
>   __dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp +  484
>
> 9  libdispatch.dylib              0x00000001d3c66ec8
>   __dispatch_workloop_worker_thread +  600
>
> 10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001d3e980dc _pthread_wqthread
>   + 300
>
> 11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x00000001d3e9acec _start_wqthread +
>   4
>
> Exception Type: NSRangeException(SIGABRT)
>
> Exception Codes: *** -[__NSArrayM setObject:atIndexedSubscript:]:
>   index 12 beyond bounds for empty array at 0x00000001d3e13104 Crashed
>   Thread: 65

Comment: What happens when you force the prediction to run on the CPU (you can specify that in your `options` argument), does it still crash? Note that iOS apps cannot use the GPU while they are in the background.

Comment: use cpu or gpu is not  crash in background,   but from background to foreground is crashed.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans for it crashes when I run it on GPU and not crashing when I run on CPU (doesn't matter background or foreground)